# Поисковая подсказка js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hint

Есть задача: сделать поисковый компонент с выпадающими подсказками + дописывание оставшихся букв в input. Выпадающие подсказки ок, но вот чтобы дописывались буквы в input задача немножко сложноватая. Есть ли какие то библиотеки для этого(js/reactjs), или как это реализуется? Пример с картинкой прикрепил
P.S вроде при нажатии на Tab это слово вписывается целиком
[image]

Comment: А что если  какой-нибудь div превратить в "инпут"? Такую реализацию делали в [craiyon.com](https://www.craiyon.com/), а там уже и буквы легко можно будет добавить.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Хорошая идея, кстати, спасибо

Comment: а что тут сложного, по вводу каждой буквы делаешь запрос на БД и выводишь результаты в выпадающем меню

Comment: Раскрою вам секрет, это не дописывание оставшихся букв :) Просто часть с совпадением выделяется более жирно или наоборот, то что не совпадает осветвляют. [Тут](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) можете посмотреть на реализацию. А то что при нажатии пропадают "серые" буквы - это тоже делается своими слушателями, при клике, просто убираются ненужные части

Comment: @EzioMercer в выпадающим списке выделение не проблема сделать, а конкретно в input'e, там где идет набор текста, идея только как написали выше, через кастомный div сделать

Comment: Можно и `span`-ами поиграться, чтобы `input` оставить. Но и со стилями надо будет динамически играться